# MCMCglmm accounting for phylogeny with lambda 0 differs from GLM

Tags: r, lambda, glm, mcmc, phylogeny

I am doing a comparative analysis with prevalence of parasitism and body mass. This data comes from 51 bird species therefore I have to correct for phylogenetic independence.

I did two analyses, one using a simple GLM and then a MCMCGLMM including the phylogeny as random factor.

Now my doubt: the results of both models are quite different, using GLM I got a pretty significant correlation but with the MCMCGLMM there is no correlation at all, however the lambda value is very low almost zero, which implies that the results from both analyses should not be too different.
This makes me think that I might have made a mistake.

here are the codes and outcomes:

**GLM**

```
m0 <- glm(cbind(M_inf,M_not_inf)~log(M.bs), data = df, family = binomial())
```

> summary(m0)

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(M_inf, M_not_inf) ~ log(M.bs), family = binomial(), data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-18.025   -1.222    1.294    4.059    9.615  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.46888    0.14458 -10.160   <2e-16 ***
log(M.bs)    0.17192    0.02369   7.256    4e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 1181.7  on 50  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1127.6  on 49  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1315.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

**GLMM**

```
inv.phylo<-inverseA(Species,nodes="TIPS",scale=TRUE)

prior<-list(G=list(G1=list(V=1,nu=0.02)),R=list(V=1,nu=0.02))

m1 <- MCMCglmm(cbind(M_inf,M_not_inf)~log(M.bs),random=~Species,
         family="multinomial2",
         ginverse=list(Species=inv.phylo$Ainv),prior=prior,
         data=df,nitt=5000000,burnin=1000,thin=500)

lambda1 <- m1$VCV[,"Species"]/(m1$VCV[,"Species"]+m1$VCV[,"units"])
mean(lambda1)
```

> summary(m1)

```
Iterations = 1001:4999501
Thinning interval  = 500
Sample size  = 9998 

DIC: 3101.985 

G-structure:  ~Species

   post.mean l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
Species    0.1828 0.001691    0.736     9689

 R-structure:  ~units

   post.mean l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp
units      2.44    1.343    3.719     9998

 Location effects: cbind(M_inf, M_not_inf) ~ log(M.bs) 

     post.mean l-95% CI u-95% CI eff.samp pMCMC
(Intercept)   0.19983 -1.86335  2.14110     9998 0.836
log(M.bs)    -0.03204 -0.35361  0.27118     9563 0.838
```

> mean(lambda1)
>   [1] 0.06234505

Any thoughts?
Many thanks

Comment: This might be a more appropriate question for Cross Validated. That said, this R-Sig-ME thread might be helpful for you, it looks like MCMCGLMM with family="multinomial2" automatically accounts for overdispersion and I don't think glm does. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q3/004480.html Your different results probably reflect that these are actually two different models and your data are overdispersed, so accounting for that overdispersion matters